# Lumen with Nginx returns white page

Tags: nginx, vagrant, lumen

I'm using the Micro-Framework Lumen and let it run with Vagrant.

So simply said: it runs when I call the website with localhost:8000 (default options) but when I try to call it with Nginx under an example URL **myawesomewebsite.com** then it does just returns a white page.

What I tried so far:

-> configured the `hosts file` from windows (added an random IP with the URL address) for instance: 55.55.55.5 myawesomewebsite.com

-> configured the `homestead.yaml`

-> installed (of course) `Nginx` on the `vagrant` machine and started it

Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "55.55.55.5"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

sites:
    - map: myawesomewebsite.com
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/project/public
```

hosts

```
55.55.55.5 myawesomewebsite.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot take a random IP, you need to use one reserved for [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) There are 3 ranges available

```
| RFC1918 name | IP address range              | number of addresses | largest CIDR block (subnet mask) |
|--------------|-------------------------------|---------------------|----------------------------------|
| 24-bit block | 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255     | 16,777,216          | 10.0.0.0/8 (255.0.0.0)           |
| 20-bit block | 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255   | 1,048,576           | 172.16.0.0/12 (255.240.0.0)      |
| 16-bit block | 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 | 65,536              | 192.168.0.0/16 (255.255.0.0)     |
```

I generally prefer to use the 192.168.0.0/16 range so for example in your Homestead.yaml file

```
---
ip: "192.168.90.51"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

sites:
    - map: myawesomewebsite.localdomain
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/project/public
```

and your windows host

```
192.168.90.51 myawesomewebsite.localdomain
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did edit these files with the same ip example. After that, I did a vagrant reload --provision but still, it does not work

Comment: arg my bad I did not pay attention, don't use a reserved extension, use localdomain for example, now it should work (if you try with chrome, try also with another browser, chrome tries to connect with google dns)

Comment: This is so weird! I just took the default ip 192.168.10.10, reloaded my vagrant machine and entered myawesomewebsite.com in the url. On chrome, there is nothing, just a white page and on firefox I'm loading a real existing domain not the fake one. So I entered 192.168.10.10 in the url and here we go, I see all my work " my acutal website ". Why does he not work with my fake domain name " myawesomewebsite.com " ?

Comment: thats why its better to use a non reserved extension - use `localdomain` instead and you should avoid those issues

Comment: Magic just happend. Restarded my pc and ahm... I don't know, it does work now. Of course, with the change, which you have suggested, so thanks for your help!