# How do I access sites on my Vagrant box via an IE VM?

Tags: internet-explorer, vagrant, virtual-machine, modern.ie

**Scenario**

I have a vagrant box:

```
...

config.vm.box = "boxname"
config.vm.hostname = "boxnameVM"
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.44"

# Configure A Few VirtualBox Settings
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.name = "boxnameVM"
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "1"]
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--ostype", "Debian_64"]
end

...
```

I have domain(s) setup on my hosts `/etc/hosts` file:

```
192.168.33.44    website.local
```

I have a Windows/IE VM from http://modern.ie

**Problem**

I can't seem to access http://website.local from within the Windows/IE VM.

Can anyone help?

Comment: please check my answer there http://stackoverflow.com/a/39807027/4296747 it will be the same issue

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @FrédéricHenri. I've amended my question. I am using the 192.168.x.x range, and I am using a non-reserved domain extension.